# Android tablet development - resolution looks like phone?

Tags: android, resolution, tablet

I notice that when I place buttons or drawable png images on my app that I'm working on and then load it on the tablet (Asus Transformer if that's relevant), it gets "spread out" and looks like crap.

I think it's assuming the resolutions are all for a phone. When I created the project I recall choosing "Android 3.0" which I thought was for tablets.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What folder are you putting your image in?

Comment: I created a folder, "drawable", which I thought saves me from using drawable-asdf (those 3 for high, medium and low - I don't want the user to have a choice here and it's annoying for me). Also, the problem is present for buttons - the resolution really looks like crap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh, add this to your manifest if you're having similar issues:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
    android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"></supports-screens>
```

Looks beautiful now.